# DDD Seperation of Domain Objects and EF Entities

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, wcf-data-services

In a recent upgrade from EF4.0 to EF5.0 and Code First some of the rules to get the Domain Model to play with Code First our team decided to split our concerns by making POCOs of the persistent object representing a 1 to 1 mapping of Databse Columns and relationships within these persistent POCOs. Using FluentApi configurations for each persistent object we tentatively called these 'persistence objects'. Some Domain objects split across several of these persistent objects utilizing abstract classes, several interfaces and sepcifications from the business rules. Since DDD refers to Domain Business Objects as 'Entities' we found this confusing since EF refers to Entities. We placed the POCOs in a separate library project. To me they began to look like DAOs.

Given the above is the choice to separate the Domain Object from the persist-able POCO contract for Code First?

The objection I raised is that this would mean the persistent objects would be exposed as a WCF Data Service objects. I halted the development until we have a small working version (our core objects can be pushed to 5 tables and 3 domain objects). I didn't want to move forward with the other 70+ POCOs until I knew for sure this was a best practice or better yet another way that fits more akin to Eric's outline in the blue book.

Comment: I may have missed something but why use these intermediate "persistent objects" and not just leverage EF fluent configurators to map your domain objects to the DB ?

Comment: Thanks.... And I'll gladly try to help out anytime with questions about DDD. I'm right in the middle of a DDD project right now so its fresh in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done that, split domain entities and EF mapping classes in separated projects. I have done that with nhibernate as well. 
Keep mapping classes in infrastructure related Project. Its knowledge about your persistance.

Regarding exposing entities for wcf services i suggest you go for an application layer and expose data with Data Transfer Object pattern. No fancy stuff. Just make you have better control over granularity of your wcf api. Usually domain entities are at such low level it requieres knowledge and multipel Calls to get the data you desire for a specific interaction (use case).

Comment: Currently we have the POCOs living in the Persistence project. We based out structure off of the NDDDSample on Google Code. https://code.google.com/p/ndddsample/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2FNDDDSample%2Fapp We are still debating on where the WCF Data Service Proxy project should be placed in the project. It looks like either "Interface" or "Infrastructure". What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Hi sry for late answer. Holiday times here in sweden :)

Comment: I would definitely treat your WCF project as a "client" - a consumer of your application service (interface). A "Client" could be a mobile app client, an external system, a web GUI... I'm a visual studio developer and to be precise I would have a AppName.Presentation project, AppName.Application project, AppName.Domain project, AppName.Infrastructure.DAL project. When it comes to WCF proxy I would place it AppName.WCFFacade. A top level layer it is. Same level as another client such as a GUI. It should only have reference to AppName.Application service layer... maybe a infra layer too